# How to Pythonically check for errors in JSON response?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a response from an API which I need to save to a database and 99% of responses all are valid with the following details which I am formatting to be neater.

I've just had a 1% response break the code because there are no address['state'] so it returned a bool of False.  I could do a try: except: for each line to catch it and if it's False but thought there must be a neater, more efficient way.

What's best practice in this instance when each line could be False?

```
order_id_newest = int(address['order_id'])
address_line_1 = address['line1'].title()
address_line_2 = address['line2'].title()
address_city = address['city'].title()
address_county = address['state'].title()
address_postcode = address['zip'].upper()
```

Comment: How are you receiving this JSON? Through `requests`? In that case, query the status code.

Comment: what do you want to happen when there's no `address['state']` ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is through requests and I already check the status code. The response is valid but sometimes address[‘state’] rather than containing a string contain a bool. This causes an error as a bool doesn’t have a .title() method. This is what I want to handle without 6 sets of try and except.

Comment: What should be the result if the value is bool?

Comment: @OmarEinea to be handled without error. Add “” if that’s sensible and ideally without several sets of try and except.

Comment: `try-except` *is the neat and pythonic and efficient way to do it*

Answer (score 1):

> Add "" if that’s sensible and ideally without several sets of try and except.

Well you could do this through dictionary's `.get(key, default)` method, like so:

```
address_county = address.get('state', '').title()
```

This will return an empty string `''` in case `address['state']` doesn't exist,
and `address_county` will be equal to `''`.